# Wordpress Multisite change new subsite admin user role

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, multisite

I have a Multisite WordPress installation that i need new people registering and creating a new sub-site within the network to get another user role not administrator. (like shop manager) in this way i will use the super admin only to do administrator tasks in all sub-sites of the network, which mean new registered sub-site user will only get shop manager role account with limited capabilities.
is there a way to do it by options or by editing the API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a general site for programming-specific questions, so you might get better help on the [WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) as that is more suited to questions about WordPress administration etc. However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: OK @FluffyKitten thank you for the guidance, i will check it now